# Complex sort using lambda

Tags: python, lambda

Is there a way to do the following python `sort` using a lambda expression?

```
sorted_urls = []
for url in all_urls:
    if '/en-' in url:
        sorted_urls.insert(0, url)
    else:
        sorted_urls.append(url)

second_sorted_urls = []
for url in sorted_urls:
    if '/season-' not in url:
        second_sorted_urls.insert(0, url)
    else:
        second_sorted_urls.append(url)
```

In other words, I want to sort it by: `'season-' not in url` ASC, `'en' in url` ASC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Tuples are naturally sorted by each element in turn, and booleans are sorted `False < True`, so just use a lambda giving a tuple key:

```
sorted_urls = sorted(all_urls, key=lambda x: ('season-' in x, 'en' not in x))
```

The booleans are inverted because the `False` values will be sorted to the beginning of the sorted list. You could also use `sorted(all_urls, key=lambda x: ('season-' not in x, 'en' in x), reverse=True))`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the focus of your question, but your code seems to have *Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)* complexity for an operation, due to the `insert(0, ...)`. Your proposed solution has *Θ ( log(n))* complexity due to the sorting. In fact, this can be done with *O(n)* time.

Say you use list comprehension for the following 4 lists.

```
without_en_without_season = [url for url in all_urls if '/en' in url and '/season' not in url]
without_en_with_season = [url for url in all_urls if '/en' in url and '/season' in url]
with_en_without_season = [url for url in all_urls if '/en' in url and '/season' not in url]
with_en_with_season = [url for url in all_urls if '/en' in url and '/season' in url]
```

You can now easily just append them in any way you like.

Comment: Personally, I think a filter looks cleaner `without_en_without_season = filter(lambda u : '/en' in u and '/season' not in u, all_urls)`

Comment: @cricket_007 I understand your point of view. It's a matter of taste, I think (there was a huge argument when designing Python3 about the place of lambdas vs. filter, map, etc. in the language itself). Nevertheless, my point was mainly algorithmic, and `filter` is equivalent in the complexity.

Comment: if you're going to do it that way, why not use a tuple `('/en' in url, '/season' in url)` and build a dict of tuple keys to lists of urls? That avoids traversing the original list four times. `urls_by_key = defaultdict(list); for url in all_urls: urls_by_key[('/en' in url, '/season' in url)].append(url)`

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper That *is* a more elegant way of doing it. Thanks! Have an upvote :-)

Comment: With that slight tweak, this is a good way to go if you're going to do anything with the grouped lists other than just concatenate them. I'd bet on `sorted` outperforming this if you do just want to concatenate them, but I admit I haven't profiled - and of course either should be fine if the input list is not very long.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you're looking for is the [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) builtin. Sorted will only sort things that are already there by default.

```
urls = ['these', 'are', 'my/en', 'test', 'urls/en']
sorted_urls_without_en = sorted(filter(lambda x: '/en' not in x, urls))
# ['are', 'test', 'these']
```

You can then sort them afterwords.

Comment: `filter` is not relevant here. The OP's example code adds all the elements of `all_urls` to each intermediate list, it just uses the booleans to determine which end of the list to add them to.

Comment: Are you sure? It looks to me like he has two independent lists by the end of it.

Comment: `sorted_urls` is an intermediary list - everything from `all_urls` goes into it at some position, then everything from `sorted_urls` goes into `second_sorted_urls`. It's just making explicit 'sort by the secondary sort key first, then sort that sorted list by the primary sort key'.